# Html select tag + option

Tags: html

How can i upgrade my select tag with additional options that can be added by a user?
F.E:

```
<select id = "sport">
    <option value = "football"> football </option>
    <option value = "volleyball"> volleyball </option>
    <option value = "rugby"> rugby</option>
</select>
```

I need there a additional text input where a user can add new option to the select tag,
If user write an another type of sport i would like to have that sport permament as a option in my select tag.

Regards,

Comment: You can use two inputs and a few lines of JavaScript to inject new items into the existing DOM. But that would be gone on page reload, so I'm not sure if that meets your definition of "permanent".

Comment: Thanks, but i need the input stays forever as a option in select.

Comment: Then you'll need to update the datasource of your dropdown options, possibly a database or sth. alike.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to the Select2 library and the "[Dynamic option creation](https://select2.org/tagging)"

```
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control js-example-tags">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>

<script>
  $(".js-example-tags").select2({
    tags: true,
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)